# Writing a negative number in text mode: $-$9 or $-9$?

Tags: formatting, symbols, best-practices, text-mode

If we want to produce -9, typing `-9` in an input file is not correct because `-` is intentionally designed for hyphenation so its glyph is bad to represent the minus sign.

To produce the minus sign, we use `$-$` instead of `-`. My question is, should a number be enclosed in `$` together with the `-` if we want to render a negative number?

In other words, which one is recommended in text mode: `$-$9` or `$-9$`?

In other words, which one is recommended out of:

### Option A

```
$-$9 is a negative number.
```

or

### Option B

```
$-9$ is a negative number.
```

?

Comment: Depends on whether you want 9 to be printed in the text font or the math font (which might be different, especially when using old-style numerals).

Comment: Obvious, but maybe useful: In case you use e.g. `\emph{$-9$}`, the number nine remains unaffected by the emphasis command, whereas `\emph{$-$9}` produces the number nine emphasised.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$-9$`

Minus nine is a number, so you should type the whole number in a single mode, in this case the math mode. If you can find a minus sign in text font, typing the sign and nine both in text mode is acceptable depend on the context.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. I saw some paper by Knuth (I think it was about the new fonts used in Concrete Math) where he mentioned that he was changing all his numbers to include the `$$`.

Comment: The Knuth paper is [here](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf), and Knuth changed *some* numbers to math mode, when there are actually math, as opposed to, say, a year.

Answer (score 28):

### Option C

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\textminus 9
\end{document}
```

This produces a legit minus sign.

Answer (score 25):

Although it's a bit overkill, you could use the `\num` macro of the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\Huge

In mathmode: \(-9\)

With \textsf{siunitx}: \num{-9}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or use a more lightweight `numprint` package.

Comment: +1 for `siunitx`

Comment: It's especially valuable if you are converting to HTML using `tex4ht`; in this case no equation (MathML or bitmap representation) is created, instead the number is printed as text. (At least in theory; I have found that [negative numbers don't work correctly out of the box](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/247)).

Answer (score 2):

I'd also say Option B or Option C since the minus sign and the number are consistently formatted in these two cases.

If you prefer Option C and your editor supports Unicode (such as Emacs) you can facilitate entering negative numbers by loading the `inputenc` or even better the `inputenx` package and associate `\textminus` with the Unicode minus sign U+2212:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\textminus}

\begin{document}

\noindent
number \textminus9\\
number −9

\end{document}
```